# Why there is 'expected an element of either String'

Tags: networkx

```
      import networkx as nx
      from bokeh.transform import linear_cmap
      from bokeh.io import show, output_notebook
      from bokeh.plotting import figure
      from bokeh.models import Circle, HoverTool, TapTool, BoxSelectTool
      from bokeh.models.graphs import from_networkx
      from bokeh.palettes import Spectral6
      output_notebook()
      G=nx.Graph(G_fb)
      plot = figure(x_range=(-1.1, 1.1), y_range=(-1.1, 1.1))
      plot.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=[("Name", "@name"), 
                               ("Club", "@club")]), 
                                TapTool(), 
                                BoxSelectTool())
      graph = from_networkx(G, nx.spring_layout, iterations=1000, scale=1, center=(0,0))
      graph.node_renderer.data_source.data['name'] = list(G.nodes())
      graph.node_renderer.glyph = Circle(size=10)
      graph.node_renderer.glyph = Circle(
      size=10, 
      fill_color=linear_cmap(degrees, palette=Spectral6,low=0, high=100, low_color='blue', high_color='red')

      plot.renderers.append(graph)
      show(plot)
```

It comes up with an error saying:

> expected an element of either String, Dict(Enum('expr', 'field', 'value', 'transform'), Either(String, Instance(Transform), Instance(Expression), Color)) or Color, got {'field': [5, 6, 12, 7, 8, 6, 6, 9, 8, 4, 3, 5, 5, 7, 5, 7, 4, 4, 3, 6, 3, 5, 10, 1, 7, 4, 8, 2, 9, 6, 5, 5, 9, 11, 11, 3, 9, 1, 10, 1, 6, 6, 5, 8, 7, 7, 4, 7, 2, 1, 3, 1, 6, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1], 'transform': LinearColorMapper(id='1194', ...)}

part of G_fb:
11 1
15 1
16 1
41 1
43 1
48 1
18 2
20 2
27 2
28 2
29 2
37 2
42 2
55 2
11 3
43 3
45 3
62 3
9 4
15 4
60 4
52 5
10 6
14 6
57 6
58 6
10 7
14 7
18 7
55 7
57 7
58 7
20 8
28 8
31 8
41 8
55 8
21 9
29 9
38 9
46 9
60 9
14 10
18 10
33 10
42 10
58 10
30 11
43 11
48 11
52 12
34 13
18 14
33 14
42 14
55 14
58 14
17 15
25 15
34 15
35 15
38 15
39 15
41 15
44 15
51 15
53 15
19 16

Comment: What is the value of `G_fb` ? Can you show a few sample of values ? Without those values it's not possible to recreate the error.

Comment: Please provide the full error message.  It will show what line the error occurs on.